# Combinatorics Problem without Repetition

Tags: combinations

I have these math problem:

Facts:

- 4 numbers consisting of numbers 0 to 9
- The first number ist not zero
- A number may not occur more than once (No repetition)

How many numbers can I generate?

My Ideas:
I have 8 possibilities for the first number.I have to calculate the other numbers with the Binomial-coefficient, but I don't exactly know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first place digit we don't have 0 at first place. So first digit can be choosen in 9 ways.

After placing one digit at first place we have 9 remaining digits. As second digit can be 0.

Similarly for 3rd place 8 options and for 4th we have 7 ways.

So total number of ways = $ 9 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 = 4536$

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks!

Comment: Your welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that the first cannot be zero, or it would be three digit.

You have 9 possibilities for the first number, since you are excluding zero.

For the second, too, you have 9, since zero can be Included here.

For the third you have 8, since 2 numbers have already been used, and similarly 7 for the last. So the total number of ways is $$9×9×8×7=4536$$